# Pandas merge_asof / combine on both index and columns

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, pdfminer

i have a dataframe with 5 columns - the first 4 are coordinates (x1, x2, y2, y1) and last column is text. these data came from a PDF text extraction module called pdfminer.

```
data_rows = [ [1, 2, 9, 4, 'A'],
              [4, 6, 13, 8, 'B'],
              [9, 10, 17, 12, 'C'] ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data_rows)
df

   0   1   2   3  4
0  1   2   9   4  A
1  4   6  13   8  B
2  9  10  17  12  C

page = df.pivot(index=[0],columns=[3],values=[4])
```

After removing multi-index from columns:

```
page 
 
3   4    8    12
0               
1    A  NaN  NaN
4  NaN    B  NaN
9  NaN  NaN    C
```

The part I am encountering challenges is when I need to merge some rows/columns. For example if I have the following structure:

```
3   4    8    9    12
0               
1    A  NaN    D  NaN
4  NaN    B  NaN  NaN
7    E  NaN  NaN  NaN  
9  NaN  NaN    F    C
```

And I am attempting to get to the following - combine columns with a tolerance of 1 (cols 8 and 9 combined) and combine rows with a tolerance of 2 (rows 7 and 9 combined)

```
3   4    8    12
0               
1    A    D  NaN
4  NaN    B  NaN  
7    E    F    C
```

is there an efficient way to do such combinations? combine_first doesn't have a tolerance parameter. merge_asof has a tolerance parameter but seems like only work on rows. thanks in advance!

**edit**: long story short - how to transform 2nd last table to last table with a tolerance parameter to control which columns/rows to combine

Comment: I try my best to understand your post, but I become confuse as I read further down on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Is there a problem with the text extraction part? Have you tried [pdfplumber?](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber) Its `.extract_text()` has `layout=True` along with other tolerance params that can be adjusted. You may also be able to use table extract methods depending on the exact layout of the pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use customer groupers and [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
# group columns by diff of 1
cols = df.columns.to_series()
cols = cols.mask(cols.astype(int).diff().le(1)).ffill()

# group indices by diff of 2
idx = df.index.to_series()
idx = idx.mask(idx.astype(int).diff().le(2)).ffill()

(df.groupby(cols, axis=1, sort=False).first()
   .groupby(idx, sort=False).first()
 )
```

*NB. index and columns must be sorted by increasing values.*

Output:

```
      4  8    12
1     A  D  None
4  None  B  None
7     E  F     C
```